# Converting a Cell Formula into VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to convert a cell formula into VBA code so users will still be able to edit a cell without removing the formula. The formula i have got so far is below but it prevents the options to add a new value into the cell. I have tried a couple of things like mirroring the cell in VBA but i am very new to this!

=E9-SUMIF('Charge Sheet'!I:I,B9,'Charge Sheet'!H:H)

Sheet 1 (Charge Sheet) -

F) Cost Centre - pulled from sheet 3

G) Job Code

H) Quantity

I) Equipment - pulled from Name in Sheet 2

J) Cost - Pulled from Unit Price (£) in Sheet 2 and multiplied by the Quantity

K) Support Staff - Updated using VBA to display the user that made the order when the other fields are filled

L) Date Issued - Updated using VBA to display the date when the order was made when the other fields are filled

Sheet 2 (Stock Levels) -

A) Item ID

B) Name

C) Unit Price (£)

D) Quantity in Stock - the cell i want to be updated when a certain item is ordered in Sheet 1

E) Re-order Level - If the Quantity in Stock falls beneath this stock level then an automatic email is sent to request re-order

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the formula, then you can just evaluate it in **VBA**

```
Sub dural()
    Dim s As String, x As Variant
    s = "E9-SUMIF('Charge Sheet'!I:I,B9,'Charge Sheet'!H:H)"
    x = Evaluate(s)
End Sub
```

This assumes that the proper sheet is already active.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for getting back to me. The issue is that i want to update the total in a different worksheet (Stock Levels, "Quality in Stock") when someone makes an order in Charge Sheet. Is that going to be possible? So the sheet that will be active is Charge Sheet and once this is changed then it updates the level in Stock Levels.

Comment: If the goal is to preserve a cell's formula while allowing a user to use an override value, then I would use a **three** cell approach.  For example, put the formula in **Z1** , leave **Z2** blank for the user and in a third cell  =IF(Z2="",Z1,Z2)  .....so the formula in **Z1** is never changed, if the user wants to override it, they place a value in **Z2**

Comment: Thank you GS, that is nearly what i am looking for. The only issue is that if the cell with the formula goes down by one it does not automically update the mirrored cell but if you update the mirrored cell then the other goes down alright.

Comment: Is there anyway to just mirror exactly what that cell shows? Is that possible at all?